# After update - no more silent notifications

Tags: support, status-completed, android-app

After recent update I no longer can elect to receive silent (no sound) notifications. The corresponding check-box disappeared and I have either to disable notifications completely or listen to default sound.

I hope that it is a bug and not a feature, since I liked that option very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option was moved to exist where the Google guidelines actually want it to exist. If you tap on "Sound" in the settings you'll see an option titled "None". This is the same way most apps (including GMail) present the option, and provides extra functionality than the toggle switch method.

Comment: When I tap on `Sound` on the `Settings` screen it wants to open some folder and does not show me any options.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a custom ROM? You're supposed to see the normal Ringtone picker you would see when tapping that button anywhere. Do you have a custom file-browser set as default to open that kind of thing?

Comment: I did have a 3rd-party file-browser (à la windows explorer). I uninstalled it and got the expected behavior.  Thank you.